# Get a "already registered" device token from The Provider

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

can I get a device token from a provider based on the contact information (e.g: phone number)?

I want to "flag" a contact who already have been installed the app.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use UDID, it is 'more' unique than carrier phone No:

`NSString *udid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];`

**UPDATE:** [It's unique, really](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier)

Comment: I don't believe that I can recognize a specific contact with the app installed based on the UDID.

Comment: @Luca: Sure you can, you can identifie a single user using his/her UDID.

Comment: Every single iOS device (iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad, Apple TV) has it's unique UDID, believe it or not :)

Comment: @JustSid: I want to indentifie a user app based on the existing phone address book, similar to WhatsApp Messenger.